# ActionScript applying rotation of sprite to startDrag()'s rectangle bounds

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, scale, trigonometry

from my main class i call to create a sprite and add it to the stage

```
private function addSwatch(evt:MouseEvent):void
 {
 if (stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(mousePoint()).length == 0)
  {
  var swatchSide:Number = 100;
  var newSwatch:Sprite = new Swatch(0 - swatchSide/2, 0 - swatchSide/2, swatchSide, swatchSide);
  newSwatch.x = mouseX;
  newSwatch.y = mouseY;
  addChild(newSwatch);
  }
 }
```

i've added a swatch sprite to the stage which, when dragged, is contained within set boundaries.

```
this.startDrag(false, swatchBounds());

...

private function swatchBounds():Rectangle
 {
 var stageBounds = new Rectangle ( 
         0 - defaultSwatchRect.x,
         0 - defaultSwatchRect.y,
         stage.stageWidth - defaultSwatchRect.width,
         stage.stageHeight - defaultSwatchRect.height
         );
 return stageBounds;
 }
```

if the square sprite is scaled, the following returned rectangle boundary works

```
private function swatchBounds():Rectangle
 {
 var stageBounds = new Rectangle ( 
         0 - defaultSwatchRect.x * swatchObject.scaleX,
         0 - defaultSwatchRect.y * swatchObject.scaleY,
         stage.stageWidth - defaultSwatchRect.width * swatchObject.scaleX,
         stage.stageHeight - defaultSwatchRect.height * swatchObject.scaleY
         );
 return stageBounds;
 }
```

now i'm trying to include the square sprites rotation into the mix.  math certainly isn't my forté, but i feel i'm on the write track.  however, i just can't seem to wrap my head around it to get it right

```
private function swatchBounds():Rectangle
 {
 var stageBounds = new Rectangle ( 
         0 - defaultSwatchRect.x * swatchObject.scaleX * Math.cos(defaultSwatchRect.x * swatchObject.rotation),
         0 - defaultSwatchRect.y * swatchObject.scaleY * Math.sin(defaultSwatchRect.y * swatchObject.rotation),
         stage.stageWidth - defaultSwatchRect.width * swatchObject.scaleX * Math.cos(defaultSwatchRect.width * swatchObject.rotation),
         stage.stageHeight - defaultSwatchRect.height * swatchObject.scaleY * Math.sin(defaultSwatchRect.height * swatchObject.rotation)
         );
 return stageBounds;
 }
```

Comment: what is this defaultSwatchRect and what does it mean?

Comment: oh, yeah that's confusing.  sorry.  it's the same as swatchObject (at this point).  defaultSwatchRect are the passed in parameters for the site to create the swatchObject.  i've edited my post so you can hopefully see what i mean

Comment: the edit did not really help clarify what defaultSwatchRect does...

Comment: sorry about that.  it's been a long day.  defaultSwatchRect (x, y, width, and height) are the passed in arguments to the Swatch constructor, which are used to create the size of the swatchObject.  there will be other objects and sprites added to the Swatch class' display list that rely on these passed in arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is that instead of using complicated trig, just get the bounding rect of swatchObject using `swatchObject.getRect()` and then create your stageBounds based on that. It should be more than good enough for your purposes.

If that is not what you want, I can help you figure out the math.

And sorry, I can't really give you a function until I figure out what defaultSwatchRect is - where its x and y is and what it's supposed to do.

Another thing you may want to keep in mind for the future: the Math functions (cos, sin) expect the angle in radians, whereas the .rotation property is in degrees, so you must convert before using.

Comment: ridiculous!  lol.  that is unbelievably way easier than what i've been trying to do all day.  thanks a million!

Comment: the result is sometimes quite a lot simpler than you thought it'd be :)
and in other cases quite a lot harder.